# New Dvds with 99 Title tracks, which one is the correct track?

Tags: macos, dvd, ripping

I have embarked on the task of backing up my DVD collection.  I have noticed that some of the newer movies I am attempting to rip contain 99 Title tracks all with approximately equal overall run times.

I use MacTheRipper to rip the DVDs and Handbrake to encode them.

My question is, is there a site somewhere that has information regarding which Title track to select?

**Disclaimer:** I cannot stress this enough, I legally own these DVDs. I am merely making a digital copy.

Two examples of such DVDs are Star Trek and Carriers.

**UPDATE:** Just an FYI each most of these 99 tracks appear to be the full length tracks. There times look to be very similar to the overall movie run time (within a few seconds of each other).  So using the time isn't a valid way to tell which is the correct track.

Opening the movie with VLC seems to be the best way to tell. Thank you all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I came across this when I was back-up some tv-shows to Apple TV. As a solution I use VLC to figure out what the right chapter number is.

Just start the DVD in VLC and start the movie/select TV show.  When it runs you can check under Playback>Chapter what the corresponding chapter# is

Comment: You can also use this same method with DVD Player

Answer (score 4):

ARCCOS is the protection schema's name.  99 is the maximum number of tracks that can be burnt to a DVD, but I don't know of a programmatic way to select the correct one or if there are web sites that perhaps contain this information.  For my Star Trek disk, the "playable" title is #21.  Same as yours?  If so, then maybe an online DVD database containing playable title numbers might be in order.  It would be easy to code, and you could make millions!!!  LOL.

Probably not, though.  Only thing you can do now is just play in your player and wait until the movie starts, then read which track it's playing.

Comment: Interesting. Citations would be nice for research purposes.

Comment: Citations for... ?

Comment: I think he means a link to where you found the information on ARCCOS

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Chris's solution, you can also divine the correct title using the Mac's DVD Player application.

Just play the movie as you normally would in DVD Player, and while the main feature is playing (don't do it during previews, or at the menu) activate the "Go" menu, select Title then take note which title in the drop down list has the tick mark next to it. Then, in Handbrake, use Open Source (Title Specific)..., to open the VIDEO_TS folder or ISO image. Don't forget to set the "scan title number" to the title number you found using DVD Player.

More here: http://wi.nr/5M

Comment: de-obfuscated link: http://forum.handbrake.fr/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=11923#p64062

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience making videos with Adobe Encore, but I may not be giving you accurate info as I do not know what made the DVD.

Usually, different tracks on DVDs are the different chapters as created in the authoring program.

The thing is that 99 chapters seems a bit much - could it possibly be an anti-piracy solution?

Are you on PC or Mac? On PC, see if you can get DVD Decrypter or imgBurn (Both by Lightning UK - Google them) to rip images of the disc or you can try Nero. Unless the disc is copy-protected these programs should do a decent job of copying the info on the discs.

Comment: It seems like it is some anti-piracy solution from the company.  I am on a mac. For pretty much every other dvd MacTheRipper or Handbrake (with VLC) works perfect.

Comment: @Mike - I don't know too much about Mac (yet). I've "been a PC" forever. Good luck to you. And yes, the 99 tracks seems like anti-piracy thing, unless the DVD has some DVD-Player extras or something. If you can get your hands on a PC, I would also test the DVD in windows Media Player to see what it comes up with. Mac may be showing windows executables on the end of the DVD as tracks.