# How can I determine which track is played when I select an entry in a DVD menu?

Tags: dvd, vlc-media-player, media, handbrake

I'm in the process of ripping some of my DVDs to my hard drive using Handbrake. Typically this is easy, I just rip every track of appropriate length (20-odd minutes for a TV show, 40-odd minutes for a movie) and--if there are multiple episodes/movies on a disc--just assume they are in order when I title them. It works great most of the time.

Some of my discs don't make this so easy, however. They contain special features, or duplicate files for different languages. This means I have to preview each track to determine which episode/movie it is before I can label it for my media center. This is extremely time consuming.

Is it possible--using a media player such as VLC or KMPlayer--to start the DVD, select my desired episode/movie from the standard DVD menu, and then determine what track the media player launches so I can easily rip said track in Handbrake?

Comment: DVDs contain CSS protection and bypassing that is a violation of the Digital Millennium Copyright Act in the USA.  Specifically, bypassing a copyright protection method is illegal.

Comment: From what I've read it's perfectly legal to rip your own media to your own hard drive for your own personal use, if you don't sell or otherwise redistribute the media. This is the only way you can make your own home media center with your purchased DVDs.

Comment: You have a right to fair use but the anti-circumvention clause trumps it legally.  Yes you have the right but you are forbidden to use it.  Yay hollywood.

Comment: I don't think handbrake makes use of libdvdcss (like vlc does) though.

Answer (score 1):

If I may be allowed to largely copy [chris laurens' answer](https://superuser.com/a/81878/40105) to another question:

> As a solution I use VLC to figure out what the right chapter number
>   is.
>
> Just start the DVD in VLC and start the movie/select TV show. When it
>   runs you can check under Playback>Chapter what the corresponding
>   chapter# is

Hope you get (or already have gotten) some closure on this.

Comment: In addition to Chapter, you may also wish to check Playback>Track as some schemes use multiple "pathways" through a standard set of chapters.